# Changing the Read More button in Minamaze Theme

Tags: wordpress

On my webpage http://leona-anderson.com/ I am using the Minamaze theme https://wordpress.org/themes/minamaze

Since the page is in german I want to change every english text into german. I am trying for hours now to change the text of the "Read More" buttons listened on the frontpage. I read throw the theme code, checked all adjustable options, but couldn`t find a way yet.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have a look for the Wordpress language support. There are files where every button label etc. is provided. This is not contained in the theme, but in the code to separate content from design...

Answer (score 1):

This goes into your functions.php

```
function excerpt_more_german( $more ) {
    return ' <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">Read more in german</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'excerpt_more_german' );
```

You can read more about it in [the excerpt's documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt)

You could check this file `admin/main/options/02.homepage.php`, I think that's what causing the problem.

Comment: Sorry, the theme is using a custom function to generate the excerpt.

Answer (score 0):

In the Theme editor for minamaze it is under admin>main>options>02.homepage.php

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.